# How to convert time values from Xh XXm to decimal

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, duration

I want to batch convert duration values in google sheets to decimal format.

The format of data that I'm getting is `2h 30m` or `1h 6m` which AFAIK is not very standard.

Expected results:

| Source | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 2h 30m | 2.5 |
| 1h 6m | 1.1 |

I've been trying using formatting options, as well as `INDEX` and `SPLIT` formulas but did not managed to achieve expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have source values in range A2:A10, then try the following formula in cell B2:

```
=arrayformula(query(regexextract(A2:A10,"(\d+)h (\d+)m")*1,"select Col1+(Col2/60) label Col1+(Col2/60) ''"))
```

Look at the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to get "digital hours." It would be better to get actual durations, like this:

`=value( regexreplace(A2:10, "(\d+)h (\d+)m", "$1:$2") )`

...or, with an array formula that evaluates multiple cells:

`=arrayformula( iferror( 1 / value( regexreplace(A2:10, "(\d+)h (\d+)m", "$1:$2") ) ^ -1 ) )`

Format the result cells as **Format > Number > Duration**. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.